# Print to specific printer using VBScript?

Tags: printing, vbscript, hta

I'm trying to have users fill out an HTA form, submit it (which will CC them a copy) and have it automatically print to a specific network computer that will only be used for this purpose.

I was able to get the form to basically print the window by using the following code:

```
<input style="margin-right: 5px;" type="button" name="Print" value="Print" Onclick="print()">
```

However, that just brings up the print dialog box that makes me choose a printer, and people won't be able to select this printer I need to use.

I've looked and tried a few things, but this has been the only thing that has worked so far. I don't want users to be able to change anything (number of copies, etc.). I just want it to print their input once they click "order".

Thanks!!

-EDIT-
I tried using `"window.print()"` as the OnClick event of the submit button, which would work, but it just brings up the print dialogue box for users to choose a printer. I need it to just automatically print it out.

Comment: You mean you've a printer in your office, and people around the world should be able to print the form using your printer?

Comment: Not people around the world, no. This form will live on our office network and will only be accessed by them. The option sort of accomplishes what I need it to, but this printer is "hidden" so there's no way to select it as an option when the print dialogue box opens. I just need it to print the values a user enters from the form automatically to this one specific printer when they click the Print/Submit button.

Comment: I just updated my question with new code I've been trying, but still can't get it to print.

Comment: Is the form really submitted to a server? If it is, you could print from the server instead of the users's machine. "LPT1:" is the path where the text file is supposed to save.

Comment: This form is simply a lunch/catering order form. A user will go fill it out before their scheduled lunch, so that they can have their order premade and ready for when they clockout so they don't have to wait in line for it to be cooked. All users are on the same network, so that could work. I was looking into having the form submit a new text file with their order, and running a script to automatically open/read/print/close each time a new file is added, but I had to leave so I didn't start that route because it seemed a little more complex to go that route.

Comment: I tried using window.Print, which works, but it still brings up the print dialogue box and makes a user select a printer. I need a way to just have it automatically print to this one printer.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't print using a printer which's driver has not been installed to user's machine. The simplest way I can imagine, is to submit the form to a server, and print the information with the specific printer via server-side code. Another way might be to use a remote script, but practical application for this is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the help.

The route I'm going now is to have the form create a .txt file on a given network drive, then creating a script to try and automatically print any new file added to that directory.